# How to add data to auto complete function in Excel or create a similar VBA that does not clear the undo/redo

Tags: excel, vba

I work with a lot of data entry - most of them are repeated that why Auto Complete helps a lot but - it has very limitation.

I would like to ask if there is code that I can add more data into Auto Complete - the data is taken from a range of table - let say Sheets("DATA")range("A1:D100")?

Comment: Have you tried Named Ranges?

Comment: I think you need a data validation... See http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/apply-data-validation-to-cells-HP010072600.aspx#BM4_1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're in need of a data validation:

1. Open **data tools** > **data validation**
2. Change the allow option to **list**
3. Enter your data either:

   - As a list with a comma separation e.g. `Yes,No,Maybe`
   - Or enter the list / range from excel e.g `=Data!$A$1:$A$100`
4. Check the in-cell drop down option.

Answer (score 1):

Data entry is best when done with a Userform.

With dropdown (comboboxes), you can fill them with anything you want and as you type, it autocompletes with anything in the list that's the best match.

This can then type onto your worksheet or wherever.